# How does WhatsApp show the name in the contact list?

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

This is bugging me about WhatsApp. My contact list in the WhatsApp app is presumably the list of contacts I have in my phone book who have WhatsApp. I can see their picture and status if they have one. But their actual usernames are as I have inputted them into my phonebook.

However, I'm sure it should appear as they have chosen their names to be (because I can choose how I want my name to be in the edit profile section). It may seem trivial, but I'm worried I'm missing something or have done something wrong.

How does WhatsApp show the name in the contact list?

P.S. I have a Samsung Galaxy S2, Android 4.1.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your WhatsApp contact list will display the names you chose for the numbers in your phonebook.

The nickname a user has is only displayed if he/she's not in your phonebook and he/she's posting in a group you're in.

Comment: The nickname also shows up in push notifications in iOS, also from Android users.

Comment: Yeah, even on windows phone; whatsapp faq says about nickname: " This name will only appear for contacts who do not already have your contact info. If your contacts are using iPhone or Windows Phone, this is the name they will see on the push notification."