# Reveal WhatApp nickname

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

[Whatsapp contact usernames](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78764/whatsapp-contact-usernames/85313#85313)

Is it possible that I can reveal the nickname on Android phone like on iOS in the push notification? Because now I have no possibility on Android to see the nickname of the user if I am not in a group with him :(